# Which is faster in .NET, .Contains() or .Count()?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to compare an array of modified records against a list of records pulled from the database, and delete those records from the database that do not exist in the incoming array. The modified array comes from a client app that maintains the database, and this code runs in a WCF service app, so if the client deletes a record from the array, that record should be deleted from the database.  Here's the sample code snippet:

```
public void UpdateRecords(Record[] recs)
{
    // look for deleted records
    foreach (Record rec in UnitOfWork.Records.ToList())
    {
        var copy = rec;
        if (!recs.Contains(rec))                      // use this one?
        if (0 == recs.Count(p => p.Id == copy.Id))    // or this one?
        {
            // if not in the new collection, remove from database
            Record deleted = UnitOfWork.Records.Single(p => p.Id == copy.Id);
            UnitOfWork.Remove(deleted);
        }
    }
    // rest of method code deleted
}
```

My question: is there a speed advantage (or other advantage) to using the Count method over the Contains method?  the Id property is guaranteed to be unique and to identify that particular record, so you don't need to do a bitwise compare, as I assume Contains might do.

Anyone?
Thanks, Dave

Comment: Why don't you set up a test application calling each 10,000 times and benchmark it?

Comment: Well, theoretically, your Count method is doing more work - the Contains would return when a match is found, your count would continue to the end.

Comment: The short answer is, the milli/micro second advantage will be lost in any network latency anyway. Chaulk this one up to premature optimization in my opinion.

Comment: Also note, that unless this causes performance problems - it's usually not worth the effort in worrying about it and you should choose the method that expresses your intention more, so Contains or Any.  Yep, someone else called it - premature optimization.

Comment: If `Record` is a class, it won't do a bitwise comparison.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This would be faster:

```
if (!recs.Any(p => p.Id == copy.Id))
```

This has the same advantages as using `Count()` - but it also **stops after it finds the first match** unlike `Count()`

Comment: @BrokenGlass: May be not faster but looks more elegant.

Comment: @JohnKZ Definitely faster and more elegant.

Comment: That's not faster than `Contains`. They have exactly the same big Oh complexity so they're basically equal. (this comment it's just to clarify your first sentence *"this would be faster"*, ok it's faster than `Count`, but not faster than `Contains` )

Comment: But `Contains` has the added complexity of relying on the object's implementation of `Equals`, which is probably slower than the lambda used by `Any`, and even potentially incorrect. Not that any of this matters, we're talking about saving microseconds here.

Comment: @digEmAll - I still would assume it's *at least* as fast as `Contains()` - depending on the definition of Equality for the `Record` class `Contains()` could be either wrong, slower or at best use the same comparison that `Any()` does - but yes Big O complexity wise they are the same.

Comment: @Matt: Of course if equality implementation is wrong or different, `Contains` can't be used ;)

Comment: `Contains` is more elegant because it more accurately describes the code's intent.  If objects with the same id should be equal than `Equals` should be overidden anyway.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: that was exactly my point. Assuming a correct and equivalent implementation of equality they're basically the same in term of performance.

Comment: Thanks for the great responses! I will use the Any method, as it expresses the intent well and is probably the better method to use no matter the underlying implementation of Equals.

Answer (score 13):

You should not even consider `Count` since you are only checking for the existence of a record. You should use `Any` instead.

Using `Count` forces to iterate the entire enumerable to get the correct count, `Any` stops enumerating as soon as you found the first element.

As for the use of `Contains` you need to take in consideration if for the specified type reference equality is equivalent to the `Id` comparison you are performing. Which by default it is not.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming `Record` implements both `GetHashCode` and `Equals` properly, I'd use a different approach altogether:

```
// I'm assuming it's appropriate to pull down all the records from the database
// to start with, as you're already doing it.
foreach (Record recordToDelete in UnitOfWork.Records.ToList().Except(recs))
{
    UnitOfWork.Remove(recordToDelete);
}
```

Basically there's no need to have an N * M lookup time - the above code will end up building a set of records from `recs` based on their hash code, and find non-matches rather more efficiently than the original code.

If you've actually got more to do, you could use:

```
HashSet<Record> recordSet = new HashSet<Record>(recs);

foreach (Record recordFromDb in UnitOfWork.Records.ToList())
{
    if (!recordSet.Contains(recordFromDb))
    {
        UnitOfWork.Remove(recordFromDb);
    }
    else
    {
        // Do other stuff
    }
}
```

(I'm not quite sure why your original code is refetching the record from the database using `Single` when you've already got it as `rec`...)

Comment: Wow, you got me there. I didn't even see I was fetching the record twice - d'oh!  I like the Except clause too, I wasn't aware of that.  great stuff!

Comment: OK, so I just tried the Except clause and it doesn't work as advertised.  The code simply deletes all the records from the database whether they existed in the incoming array or not.  Given this uses a 3rd-party commercial ORM, I'm guessing things aren't as you assumed they might be.  Back to the Any clause, I guess.

Comment: @DaveN59: Well it does rely on GetHashCode and Equals being implemented correctly, yes. There are still alternatives if you're interested (e.g. a dictionary from ID to Record) but if `Any` is working well for you, then you might as well stick with that.

Answer (score 6):

`Contains()` is going to use `Equals()` against your objects. If you have not overridden this method, it's even possible `Contains()` is returning incorrect results. If you have overridden it to use the object's `Id` to determine identity, then in that case `Count()` and `Contains()` are almost doing the exact same thing. Except `Contains()` will short circuit as soon as it hits a match, where as `Count()` will keep on counting. `Any()` might be a better choice than both of them.

Do you know for certain this is a bottleneck in your app? It feels like premature optimization to me. Which is the root of all evil, you know :)

Comment: More curiosity than anything else.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're guarenteed that there will be 1 and only 1, Any might be faster. Because as soon as it finds a record that matches it will return true.

Count will traverse the entire list counting each occurrence.  So if the item is #1 in the list of 1000 items, it's going to check each of the 1000.

**EDIT**

Also, this might be a time to mention not doing a premature optimization.

Wire up both your methods, put a stopwatch before and after each one.
Create a sufficiently large list (1000 items or more, depending on your domain.)  And see which one is faster.

My guess is that we're talking on the order of ms here.

I'm all for writing efficient code, just make sure you're not taking hours to save 5 ms on a method that gets called twice a day.

Answer (score 2):

It would be so:

```
UnitOfWork.Records.RemoveAll(r => !recs.Any(rec => rec.Id == r.Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest an alternative approach that should be faster I believe since count would continue even after the first match.

```
public void UpdateRecords(Record[] recs)
{
    // look for deleted records
    foreach (Record rec in UnitOfWork.Records.ToList())
    {
        var copy = rec;
        if (!recs.Any(x => x.Id == copy.Id)
        {
            // if not in the new collection, remove from database
            Record deleted = UnitOfWork.Records.Single(p => p.Id == copy.Id);
            UnitOfWork.Remove(deleted);
        }
    }
    // rest of method code deleted
}
```

That way you are sure to break on the first match instead of continue to count.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know the actual number of elements, use Count(); it's the only way. If you are checking for the existence of a matching record, use Any() or Contains(). Both are MUCH faster than Count(), and both will perform about the same, but Contains will do an equality check on the entire object while Any() will evaluate a lambda predicate based on the object.